# Unresolved Externals when function is already called?

Tags: c++

I have this code but I keep receiving the unresolved externals error for intiboard? Does anybody have an idea why this is happening? I thought that I did this correctly because I have a function prototype as well as called it in the main function and defined it at the end of the code. And all of the parameters are referenced to. Also i did not include the other definitions to the other function in the program.if I comment out the initboard in my main, the code compiles fine. 
This is the error I get:
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl initboard(int * const,int)" (?initboard@@YAXQAHH@Z) referenced in function _main

fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <algorithm>
   using namespace std;

   const int size1=80;
   const int size2=10;
   const int size3=20;

   void initboard(int keno[], int size1);//initialize the keno board
   void twentnum(int keno[], int size3,int size1);//twenty randomly selected numbers
   void matches(int keno[],int guess[],int guess1[],int& numofmatches,int size1,int size2);
   void dispkeno(int keno[],int guess1[],int size1);//displays keno board
   void dispmess(int guess[], int numofmatches,int size2);

   int main()
   {
       int keno[size1];//keno board array
       int guess[size2];//guess array
       int guess1[size3];//first guess array
       int numofmatches;//number of matches

      //This code represents a game keno that chooses twenty random numbers 
    //from 1-80 and asks the user for 10 numbers from 1-80. The code then 
    //finds the matches between the users array and the randomly selected 
    //number array.

       initboard(keno,size1);
       twentnum(keno,size3,size1);
       matches(keno,guess,guess1,numofmatches,size1,size2);
       dispkeno(keno,guess1,size1);
       dispmess(guess,numofmatches,size2);

       return 0;
   }

   void intiboard(int keno[], int size1)
   {
    int i;
       for(i=1;i<size1+1;i++)
       {
        keno[i]=0;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelled it wrong :) `intiboard` should be `initboard` in the function definition.